# Array Subtraction

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
    List<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
    double[]numbers= {13,17,14};
    //Arrays.sort(numbers);
    // start with last number
    
   // double diff = numbers[numbers.length-1];
    //double temp =  0;
    list2.add((double)0);
   
    for(int j =1;j<=numbers.length-1;j++) {
        double temp =  0;
        double temp2 = 0;
         int cnt1 =0;
        // System.out.println("cnt1 --> "+cnt1);
        for (int i=j; i>=0; i--) {
            
      // substract other number one by one                                        
            if(i > numbers.length-1) {
                
                break;
            }
             System.out.println("Answer i --> " + i +" - " +numbers[i]);
            // System.out.println("Answer cnt1 --> " + cnt1 +" - " +numbers[cnt1]);
             
            //temp =  numbers[i] -numbers[cnt1];
             
            
             temp = temp - numbers[i]  ;
            temp =  Math.abs(temp); 
             System.out.println("temp --> "+temp);
            //cnt1++;
            //System.out.println("cnt1 --> "+cnt1);
        }
        
        list2.add(temp);
        
        //temp = 0;
    }
 //   System.out.println("Answer --> "+diff);
    System.out.println("Answer --> "+list2);
```

I am writing code to perform the substraction of array element. For given array element substraction array element should (0,4,-16) . First element is 0 because no element at left side of first element. Can you please suggest why I am getting (0,4,10) instead of (0,4,-16)

Comment: Step through your program with the debugger

Comment: Use a debugger my friend.

Comment: yes..that's right...what should I do to get array (0,4,-16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the last iteration, `temp - numbers[i]` becomes `3 - 13` which results in `-10`. When the absolute value is taken using `Maths.abs(temp)`, the value becomes `10`. Hence, you obtain the result as `[0,4,10]`.

Since you are sequentially trying to subtract the elements, during each subtraction, the result should be stored in a `temp` variable and subtracted again from the previous `temp` variable value.

For example, if we consider the second iteration which subtracts `14 - 17 - 13`,

- during the first subtraction -> `temp = 14 - 17 = -3`
- during the second subtraction -> `temp = temp(-3) - 13 = -16`

From this we can see that, before the first subtraction, if we put `14` in to the `temp` variable, you will get the expected output.

- during the first subtraction -> `temp = temp(14) - 17 = -3`
- during the second subtraction -> `temp = temp(-3) - 13 = -16`

The first subtraction occurs within the second loop. So, within the first loop, we can assign the first value which should be considered for the subtraction to the `temp` variable.

You could modify your loops as follows.

```
for(int j=1; j<=numbers.length-1; j++) {
    double temp = numbers[j];
    for (int i=j; i>0; i--) {
        temp = temp - numbers[i-1];
    }
    list2.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: yes..that's right...what should I do to get array (0,4,-16)